# Paperclip and mongoid background processing

Tags: background, mongoid, delay, delayed-job, resque

is there any gem for process paperclip jobs in background?

I found delayed_job and resque, but both are for active record not monogid

Regards,

Comment: what did you end up using?

Answer (score 2):

i used [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) before and it was working fine doing the background jobs with paperclip... the only issue I had with it, is that sometimes (scenarios ) are really hard to implement or test using rspec.... like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992908/save-paperclip-image-from-url-in-a-background-job) but it was really a scenario not often used...( i want to fetch the image from url in background job)

there is also other solutions you can look into... it's not exactly doing the background job implementation ( it's a pubsub pattern implementation) like the following gems

- [wisper](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper)
- [wisper async](https://github.com/krisleech/wisper-async)

you can add events when on specific actions and respond to them in the background ( using wisper-async)

the benefits of using this wisper approach is that it provides simple pubsub pattern that works like background jobs... and it's the only background **free** solution that works with heroku... plus it provides a good solution to decouple and simplify your application

check this http://artmees.github.io/blog/2014/04/02/on-rails-pub-slash-sub-pattern/ for extra info on using pubsub pattern...

one last thing (*I'm not sure about*)... I think there are no problems using resque or delayed_job with mongoid... although I didn't try them.